# 3sum LTE at leetcode

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am doing the 3sum problems at leetcode.com

Brute force 's time complexity is O(N^3).

I use a hashtable so i think the time complexity is O(N^2).

However, I still got a TLE (Time Limit Exceeded)

how can i speed up my code ?

below is my code

thanks a lot !

```
class Solution public:
vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {

    vector<vector<int>> ANS;
    if(nums.size() < 3) return ANS;

    map<int,int*> hashtable;
    map<int,int*>::iterator it;
    vector<int> ans;

    for(int i=0;i < nums.size();i++)
    {

        for(int j=i+1;j < nums.size();j++ )
         {

            it = hashtable.find(nums[j]);
            if(it != hashtable.end() ) //found target
            {
                ans.push_back(nums[j]);
                ans.push_back((it)->second[0]);
                ans.push_back((it)->second[1]);
                sort(ans.begin(),ans.end());
                ANS.push_back(ans);

                ans.clear();

            }
            else
            {
                int* temp = new int[2];
                temp[0]=nums[i];
                temp[1]=nums[j];
                hashtable[0-nums[i]-nums[j]]=temp; 

            }
         } 
         hashtable.clear();

    }
    sort( ANS.begin(), ANS.end() );
    ANS.erase( unique( ANS.begin(), ANS.end() ), ANS.end() );
    return ANS;
}};
```

Comment: Question asking to improve working code should really be asked on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: sorry i will delete this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not really of `O(n^2)`, it's definitely costly than `O(n^2)`. And solution in `O(n^2)` without any optimization won't pass the OJ. Here is my solution which is `O(n^2)`. I've put comments in the code with explanation.

```
vector<vector<int> > threeSum(vector<int> &num) {
    vector <vector<int> > result;
    size_t n = num.size();
    if(n < 3) return result;

    vector<int> solution(3);
    sort(num.begin(), num.end());
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 2; ++i) {
        int start = i + 1, end = n - 1;

        while(start < end) {
            int sum = num[start] + num[end] + num[i];
            if(sum == 0) {
                solution.at(0) = num[i];
                solution.at(1) = num[start];
                solution.at(2) = num[end];
                result.push_back(solution);
                // these loops will skip same elements and fasten the algorithm
                // while(start < n - 1 and num[start] == num[start + 1]) start++;
                // while(end > i + 1 and num[end] == num[end - 1]) end--;
                start++, end--;
            } else if(sum > 0) {
                // while(end > i + 1 and num[end] == num[end - 1]) end--;
                end--;
            } else {
                // while(start < n - 1 and num[start] == num[start + 1]) start++;
                start++;
            }
        }
        while(i < n - 1 and num[i] == num[i + 1]) i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Let me know if you have any question. Hope it helps!

Comment: really help me a lot ! nice